# View raspberry pi screen in web browser

Tags: remote, vnc, web-browsers, web

Is there an easy way to view a remote Raspberry Pi screen in my web browser? Kinda like VNC, except view-only. And, you know, in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can literally run a VNC server on your RPi, view it in a browser, and set it to be read only :)

First, see http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/ for instructions on installing VNC on your RPi.  I haven't done it, but it seems pretty straight forward.

Second, you can set it in read-only mode.  See  https://superuser.com/questions/385545/can-vnc-server-be-put-into-a-read-only-mode for reference.

Lastly, there are several VNC clients that are web based.  Something like https://www.realvnc.com/products/chrome/ would probably do the trick.